# Firebase returns different results for the same query. iOS

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a departmental structure when entering via email and a password, I'm looking for a model of the Department by email, but encountered an error, the result can be different for the same data. For example, if the first approach, the query returns the model, with the following query can return `NSNull`.

The data structure of departments.

```
{
  "departments" : {
    "19537648-B6DA-4F63-9AFF-EFC4754630D6" : {
      "createdAt" : "502100506.440385",
      "email" : "dev@test.com",
      "isCertified" : false,
      "isMain" : false,
      "mainVendorID" : "YeLf8kzE1LfWwHnWwLJTWsaPinI3",
      "title" : "",
      "uid" : "19537648-B6DA-4F63-9AFF-EFC4754630D6"
    },
    "4552E741-B9B6-4733-84C1-7DE7FFC0FD4B" : {
      "createdAt" : "502100536.218835",
      "email" : "department@test.com",
      "isCertified" : false,
      "isMain" : false,
      "mainVendorID" : "YeLf8kzE1LfWwHnWwLJTWsaPinI3",
      "title" : "",
      "uid" : "4552E741-B9B6-4733-84C1-7DE7FFC0FD4B"
    },
    "DBEFBF16-71FE-4AB6-BEA6-5BF042D1AB1D" : {
      "createdAt" : "502100521.083035",
      "email" : "tester@test.com",
      "isCertified" : false,
      "isMain" : false,
      "mainVendorID" : "YeLf8kzE1LfWwHnWwLJTWsaPinI3",
      "title" : "",
      "uid" : "DBEFBF16-71FE-4AB6-BEA6-5BF042D1AB1D"
    }
  }
```

My request

```
let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
          .child(FirebaseDatabaseManager.DatabaseMainGateways.departments.rawValue)
          .queryOrdered(byChild: "email").queryEqual(toValue: departmentEmail)

ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
    if snapshot.value is NSNull {
        debugPrint(“value is NSNull”)
        notExist?()
    } else {

    }
}, withCancel: { (error) in

})
```

What could be the problem and how to fix it? Thanks!

**UPDATE**

Firebase rules

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": "auth != null",

    "departments": {
      ".indexOn": "email"
    },

  }
}
```

**UPDATE 1**

Task Next, it was necessary to make sure that when we go to the main vendor (normal Firebase user who can log in using Google plus or an email) to the user to create their own departments (users with special limitations to the data). Firebase does not allow to register new users in the system if we already have an account, but it had to be to the main vendor could pass username and password to his department. So I did differently. When creating a new department (by email) I first check whether the email already at the creation of another department in the list of the main vendor added.

```
func addDepartment(departmentModel: RealmVendor, success: (() -> Void)?, isCreated: (() -> ())?, fail: ((_ error: Error) -> ())?) {
    guard let currentVendor = RealmManager.shared.getCurrentVendor(isMain: true) else { return }

    let checkingQuery = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child(FirebaseDatabaseManager.DatabaseMainGateways.vendors.rawValue).child(currentVendor.uid).child(DatabaseMainVendorGateways.departmentsEmails.rawValue).queryEqual(toValue: departmentModel.email).queryOrderedByValue()

    queries.append(checkingQuery)

    checkingQuery.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        if snapshot.value is NSNull {
            // creating a new department
            debugPrint("Create a new department")
            self.createDepartment(departmentModel: departmentModel, success: {
                success?()
            }, fail: { (error) in
                fail?(error)
            })
        } else {
            // department was created
            debugPrint("department was created")
            isCreated?()
        }
    }) { (error) in
        debugPrint("error", error)
        fail?(error)
    }
}
```

The next step, if the Department was not created by this email, then I add the email to the list of models of the main vendor

```
private func createDepartment(departmentModel: RealmVendor, success: (() -> Void)?, fail: ((_ error: Error) -> ())?) {
    guard let currentVendor = RealmManager.shared.getCurrentVendor(isMain: true) else { return }
    let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child(FirebaseDatabaseManager.DatabaseMainGateways.vendors.rawValue).child(currentVendor.uid).child("departmentsEmails").childByAutoId()
    ref.keepSynced(true)

    references.append(ref)

    ref.setValue(departmentModel.email) { (error, ref) in
        if error == nil {
            // save department to realm that we can show all departments in department list in app
            debugPrint("save department to realm", departmentModel.uid)

            RealmManager.shared.saveVendor(departmentModel)

            self.createFirstDepartmentModel(departmetnModel: departmentModel)
            success?()
        } else {
            fail?(error!)
        }
    }
}
```

Then I call the function to create the first model of the Department.

```
private func createFirstDepartmentModel(departmentModel: RealmVendor) {
    FirebaseDatabaseDepartmentManager.shared.savePreservationDepartmentOnServer(departmentModel)
}


func savePreservationDepartmentOnServer(_ realmDepartment: RealmVendor) {
    let refDatabase = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child(FirebaseDatabaseManager.DatabaseMainGateways.vendorDepartments.rawValue).child(realmDepartment.mainVendorUID!).child(realmDepartment.uid)

    references.append(refDatabase)

    refDatabase.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        if let _ = snapshot.value as? [String : Any] {
            // already existed. save the updated model, since the seller has already registered with the server, and not to spoil its current data
        } else {
            refDatabase.keepSynced(true)
            // it isn't existed.  save a new model, as the seller is not registered on the server
            let userInfoDict = realmDepartment.toJSON()

            refDatabase.setValue(userInfoDict) { (error, ref) in
                if error == nil {
                    self.createPath(realmDepartment)
                } else {
                    debugPrint(error!.localizedDescription)
                }
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Then, create a path model, in order to sign up for a user account department, he was able to find the way to your model in the database.

```
private func createPath(_ departmentModel: RealmVendor) {
    let pathRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child(FirebaseDatabaseManager.DatabaseMainGateways.departmentsPath.rawValue).child(departmentModel.uid)
    pathRef.keepSynced(true)

    references.append(pathRef)

    let path = PathModel()
    path.email = departmentModel.email!
    path.mainVendorUID = departmentModel.mainVendorUID!

    let pathJSON = path.toJSON()

    pathRef.setValue(pathJSON) { (error, ref) in

    }
}
```

Then, when a user visits a department, then he has only two fields, the field entering email address and password. After he entered his email, I first check the availability of email in an array of paths (hereinafter mistake here).

```
func searchDepartmentPathModel(_ byEmail: String, success: (() -> Void)?, fail: ((_ error: Error) -> Void)?, notExist: (() -> Void)?) {

    let query = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child(FirebaseDatabaseManager.DatabaseMainGateways.departmentsPath.rawValue).queryOrdered(byChild: "email").queryEqual(toValue: byEmail)

    queries.append(query)

    query.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        if snapshot.value is NSNull {
            debugPrint("searchDepartmentPathModel is NSNull there is not department path model", query.debugDescription)
            notExist?()
        } else {
            debugPrint("searchDepartmentPathModel is success", query.debugDescription)
            guard let _value = snapshot.value else { return }
            guard let valueDictionary = _value as? [String : [String : Any]] else { return }
            guard let modelDictionary = valueDictionary.first else { return }
            guard let path = Mapper<PathModel>().map(JSON: modelDictionary.value) else { return }

            // Saving department path
            let realmDepartmentManager = RealmDepartmentManager()

            realmDepartmentManager.saveDepartmentPath(path: path)

            success?()
        }
    }, withCancel: { (error) in
        fail?(error)
    })
}
```

If this search finds a model way with this an email, I will first try to register the user, because if the user is already registered returns a specific error code 17007 (this means that the entry in the account is not the first), I will call other functions with the usual input. After the first login, I replace the id of the model department (when you first create your id I generate, then I set the user id from Firebase).

The very structure of the data we obtain the following

```
{
  "departmentsPath" : {
    "i11uK8erW2OYJPMQnnoOr0vRGca2" : {
      "email" : "apple@test.com",
      "mainVendorUID" : "V4lHBFY24rXTRrsvbZloYGjJwkZ2"
    }
  },
  "vendorDepartments" : {
    "V4lHBFY24rXTRrsvbZloYGjJwkZ2" : {
      "i11uK8erW2OYJPMQnnoOr0vRGca2" : {
        "createdAt" : "502381326.78624",
        "email" : "apple@test.com",
        "information" : {
          "address" : "3 Temasek Blvd, Suntec City, Suntec City Mall, Singapore 038983",
          "departmentTitle" : "Apple",
          "id" : "D8D7CC3A-E8CC-45AF-A71D-AAAB2E5F776F",
          "location" : {
            "id" : "D8D7CC3A-E8CC-45AF-A71D-AAAB2E5F776F",
            "latitude" : 1.2929781,
            "longitude" : 103.8570364
          },
          "phoneNumber" : "688",
          "storeManagerID" : "7",
          "storeManagerName" : "Tim"
        },
        "isCertified" : false,
        "isMain" : false,
        "mainVendorUID" : "V4lHBFY24rXTRrsvbZloYGjJwkZ2",
        "title" : "My Store",
        "uid" : "i11uK8erW2OYJPMQnnoOr0vRGca2"
      }
    }
  },
  "vendors" : {
    "V4lHBFY24rXTRrsvbZloYGjJwkZ2" : {
      "createdAt" : "502370885.980612",
      "departmentsEmails" : {
        "-KXzuTG8tZx9Fuyx3jJ8" : "apple@test.com"
      },
      "displayName" : “Alex”,
      "email" : “*******@gmail.com",
      "isCertified" : false,
      "isMain" : true,
      "photoPath" : "https://lh6.*****/-*/**/AAAAAAAAAA8/**/s96*c/photo.jpg",
      "title" : "My Store",
      "uid" : "V4lHBFY24rXTRrsvbZloYGjJwkZ2"
    }
  }
}
```

The error lies in the fact that the two scenarios I can not find ways to model returns NSNull. The first scenario is when a user visits a department for the first time, coming out of the account and is trying to re-enter, the request can not find a model way. The second scenario, you can not find ways to model, if you go to Account Department (the first and subsequent visits) come out of it, and try to log in to another account in the department that has not been logged. Helps only delete the application from a device.

Comment: try to set a rule for indexing in firebase for the email, something like that:` {
    "rules": {
        ".read": true,
        ".write": true,
        "departments": {
              ".indexOn": ["email"]
        }
    }
}` but this format just for you to know not to use.

Comment: @Jad I have such rules, but one that can not be recorded when the user is not logged in.

Comment: and the root for the database is "departments"?

Comment: @Jad There are several roots, one of them is "departments". For example another root "vendors".

Comment: What is the output you expect of that code? And what is the output you actually get?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Sometimes a dictionary (the model with this email) and sometimes in the same database returns NSNull

Comment: Hmmm.... that seems weird. Any idea on what makes the difference? Does it happen at specific times/intervals?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen This result is absolutely randomly. My user cases I got this result. 1 Create the model with the main vendor (main account), I go out with it, trying to go to a department get this error. 2 I go out with account, delete the app from your device, re-compile, at the first entrance as I get this error. 3 Startup without Xcode, and the installation through the Fabric.

Comment: I duplicated your code and structure with one change - I simplified the path to myRootRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "email").queryEqual(toValue: departmentEmail). It worked 100% of the time. So that says that either the path is not being set correctly or something else is causing the issue.

Comment: @Jay Thank you very much for your review.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Hello again. I found an algorithm in which the action turns out very clearly, to paint step by step. 1 When we went as a major vendor (through Google Plus or email). 2 registered department. 3 Exit from the main account. 4 inputs for the first time as a department (and register it). 5 Exit out of it and try to go again get this error. P.S. When we booked the department, remove the application, and go again (sign in action), everything works fine.

Comment: Can you update your question with the [minimal steps that are needed to reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? That way we can try to reproduce it and will have a much easier time troubleshooting.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Good day, please see Update 1, I posted all the functions involved in this process.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Please read my answer, I disabled the cache Firebase SDK and issues no longer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a similar behavior in another case, now I describe it. I have several categories, and a boolean value that the standard categories set true. I just completely removed the structure of categories, but I came back the answer 1 or true, which they are installed, but had to return `NSNull`. I thought that the problem is in the cache, after reading [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38677241/firebase-is-retrieving-deleted-data-from-database/38677531#38677531) confirmed my opinion. I tried to disable the cache in this way Firebase SDK `FIRDatabase.database().persistenceEnabled = false` (Prior to this, the value was true), after getting off the result cache is always correct. I would like to learn how you can fix the problem so you could use Firebase SDK cache.